# How to convert resx file property of Build Action to Content using c# code?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0, resx

My question is, currently I am having a resx file example, English.resx and its Build Property as Embedded resource. So, I can't edit the file after build. To edit the file I have changed the Build action property to Content for the English.resx manually and I can edit it after build. But, I need to convert the build action property using C# code. So that I will choose the file to convert from front end, and its build action property needs to be changed to content using C#.

In the Below picture I have changed the build property to content manually using visual studio. But it needs to be changed using C# Code. Is it possible to change using the C# code?

[image]

Comment: This is set in the project file.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you are looking for. Indeed you can change properties by editing .csproj files (which are just XML - there are tons of questions about modifying XML that you likely already looked at)... Is that what you are looking for? Or you trying to achieve something else? Please [edit] question to clarify.

Comment: Assuming that this is a winforms or a console application project, again guessing that you want to modify the resources on-the-fly, please search the web for "using custom resource manager C#"

Comment: Thanks  Oguz, but I couldn't able to get what I am looking for. Do you have any other idea on how to change the build action during run time for a resx file.

Answer (score 0):

In the project item group I used content to change the build action for all the files with .resx

```
<ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="*.resx" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Thanks to all.